# Netty 4.0 proper/elegant way to implement reponse timeout?

Tags: netty

I'm new to Netty and I come from the one thread per connection world. I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement timing-out waiting for a response on a channel. In the blocking world, you'd send a packet to a remote peer, and you'd wait in the thread for a response. If the response doesn't come in time, you'd throw an exception or ...etc.

One way to accomplish this (that might not fit with the Netty way of things) is to create a timer when the request is sent, and cancel it if you get a response in time, or throw an exception if not.

Any help that would send me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may want to check out how [IdleStateHandler](http://netty.io/4.0/xref/io/netty/handler/timeout/IdleStateHandler.html#302) is implements the timeouts

Comment: Thanks for this. The IdleStateHandler might be too generic for what I'm looking for, I'm looking for a way to specifically target a particular request. For example, I might send three requests and get back only two responses. I want to be able to assign a timeout for every request sent. An IdleStateHandler wouldn't help here because there might be other traffic on the channel

Answer (score 1):

After doing more research, the best way I could come up with to solve this is to schedule a Runnable on the channel eventloop with the desired timeout. If the response comes back before the timeout, I can cancel the ScheduledFuture, otherwise I'll get the response timeout I was looking for. Compared to the IdleStateHandler, I can now have a ScheduledFuture per request sent and be able to track my responses.